# CodeIgniter adding content generating Forbidden

Tags: codeigniter, session

A web site I have published is generating the error stated below when a valid user submits form content to be stored in the database:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php/user/add on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an 
ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

This is a private web site.  All users have to log-in.  Some users can add content.  Using CI sessions there is an added field of `edit`, with a value of 0 or 1 retrieved from the user's record in the user table, copied to the `user_data` session array at the time of log-in.  The variable `$this->session->userdata('edit')` is used for if statements in the controller and views.  Value of 1, user will see links that will bring up views (forms) to edit or add content.

This is a snippet for how I am using the variable to set menu items:

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('edit') == 1) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url().'/user/add'; ?>">Add</a></li>
<?php }; ?>
```

This is the basic structure for the processing of form data. This function is in the controller file `user.php`:

```
function add(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') ){
            //runs form validation
        if ( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) {
            //if false, redisplays the form and data with failed fields highlghted
        }//if
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            //processes the data and stores in the database
        }//form validation run
    } else {
        redirect ("user/login");
    } //if...else
}//add
```

Examining the database after one of these Forbidden errors, no data is inserting. A redisplayed form due to validation error(s) is not happening either.  These factors lead me to believe this is a server problem more than a CodeIgniter issue.  [If you look at this link](http://picpaste.com/403_Forbidden-2014-06-06-11.57.10-QeOFIkBt.png) it shows a screen shot of the error received in the browser (either Firefox or Chrome, other browsers not in use yet), it is not the usual CodeIgniter appearance for an error generated from a mistake in CI code.

The add/edit content forms are working well. As stated above, the error occurs at time of form submission.  As well, it is only happening on the hosting company's server. I have checked the permissions of `user.php` and they are 644 like the rest of the files.

What are possible fixes?  If it is a server issue, what do I look for or ask my hosting company to look at?  If it is a CI sessions issue, in the documentation CodeIgniter states it uses a system different from $_SESSION super global.  Is it wise to copy the user data to that array and have the code look up the data from that variable array? Or do I create a distinct array and save the keys there?

**Revision and Solution**
I retested the connection to the database associated with this project.  I could connect.  Taking things a next step, I could select records but not insert.  I performed those tests with raw, simple statements.

Examining privileges for this user and the database, I discovered that while All Privileges was checked, none of the individual privileges was checked. (See [this screen shot](http://picpaste.com/Panelbox_-_Funio-2014-06-11-09.41.13-75HxnvVY.png).)

I ignored the All Privileges check-box and manually checked each of the other boxes.  Conducting small tests like the ones outlined above and then interacting with the form on the site, I am getting results I expect.

Things I don't understand:

1. How can All Privileges be checked and none of the other check-boxes checked?

I have gone back and tried to check All Privileges and then uncheck the others individually.  It's not possible.  From interacting with Panelbox on this host often to set-up users and associate them with a database, I know it is not usual for the state I found described above.

1. Programmatically, since there is only one user and set of privileges associated with a CodeIgniter site, how was the admin for this site able to insert 5 records in the database before a Forbidden error started being returned from the server?

I did not outline it when I first posted this thread, but the Forbidden error did not happen right away with uploading and running the site from the server.  Since the admin was able to submit five completed forms perfectly before starting to receive errors, I presumed it was a Sessions problem.  This contention was also arrived at because sometimes deleting the cookie and then logging in, I or the admin was able to submit a form and the data was inserted in the database.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: anytime codeigniter has given me a forbidden error, it was because the global CSRF protection was enabled in /application/config/config.php

Comment: This looks like more of a problem with the routing than sessions.  That's the default apache error page, which usually comes up if you're trying to access a page that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jon Best CSRF in /application/config/config.php is not enabled

Comment: @SamDufel Routing has not been altered from the defaults.  I don't think the error can be happening for lack of a page. The functions in the controller file to call the forms (before handing off to the view) exist in the same controller file as `user.php` mentioned above which holds the function `add`

Comment: @dwlamb - as a sanity check, comment out the entire contents of the `add` method and just add `echo "hello"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test user privileges associated with a database often.  Sometimes things change.